# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null when pressing any key react reactjs javascript redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I am new to react and trying to show update values of an input field. When I press any key, it throws the TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null error.

```
onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      profile: {
        ...prevState.profile,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,  //this is where the error is pointed
      },
    }));
```

this is my state and I am setting my state in `componentDidUpdate` after getting my values from the redux store.

state:

```
state = {
    title: "Create Your Profile",
    profile: {},
    errors: {},
    toggleSocialProfileInput: false,
  };
```

componentDidUpdate:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.errors !== prevProps.errors)
      this.setState({ errors: this.props.errors });
    if (this.props.profileReducer !== prevProps.profileReducer)
      this.setState({ profile: data, title: "Edit Your Profile" });
  }
```

I am using these as input where I am setting my values using profile state

```
const { profile } = this.state;

               <TextField
                placeholder="* Profile Handle"
                name="handle"
                value={profile.handle}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                error={errors.handle}
                info="A unique handle for your profile URL. Your full name, company name, nickname"
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Status"
                name="status"
                value={profile.status ? profile.status : ""}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                error={errors.status}
                info="What are you upto? Or some quote"
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Location"
                name="location"
                value={profile.location ? profile.location : ""}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                error={errors.location}
                info="City or City, State (eg. Toronto, ON)"
              />
```

And if you want to see my TextField component:

```
const TextField = ({
  name,
  placeholder,
  error,
  info,
  type,
  icon,
  disabled,
  value,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const containerClass = icon ? "input-group mb-3" : "form-group";
  return (
    <div className={containerClass}>
      {icon && (
        <div className="input-group-prepend">
          <span className="input-group-text">
            <i className={icon} />
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
      <input
        type={type}
        className={`form-control form-control-lg ${error && "is-invalid"}`}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
      {info && <small className="form-text text-muted">{info}</small>}
      {error && <div className="invalid-feedback">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

One way I know is that instead of profile I can declare the names of the textfields in the state but I want to keep the code short and thus want to use the profile object in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting state using a callback. So first define `e.target` in a variable, then use it in your setState callback.

**This should work**

```js
onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      profile: {
        ...prevState.profile,
        [target.name]: target.value, 
      },
    }));
```

With [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling),

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Thanks. I still didn't quiet catch it why it happens but yeah eventually defining a new e.target variable did help. TA
P.S I can't upvote your answer since I am new on stackoverflow.